# How to use Django DateTimeField's default

Tags: python, database, django, django-models, default

I'm trying to use `datetime.datetime.now` as the default for my `pub_date` column, but keep getting an error.

`DatabaseError: (1054, "Unknown column 'archive_app.pub_date' in 'field list'")`

I'm just testing out my code in `python manage.py shell` so the line I use when getting the error is simply `App.objects.all()`

Here's my model code for the app

```
import datetime
from django.db import models

class App(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('pub date', default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

Comment: Have you ran `syncdb` or used a [migration tool](http://south.aeracode.org/) for the updated schema?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your default as far as I can see, but your database is complaining it has no such column in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ran `syncdb`, did you have `pub_date` defined on `App`?

If you added it after syncdb then did you create and run the migration?

Comment: Yes, after I added pub_date in my code I ran `python manage.py syncdb`

Comment: I mean did you first have only two fields `title` and `votes` and then ran syncdb. And after syncing you later added `pub_date`?

Comment: In that case, you need to run a migration to add this third column `pub_date` to your table. `syncdb` won't do this task. `syncdb` only reads the `models.py` and see if there is some Model for which a table doesn't exist, and in that case creates the table. `syncdb` won't alter the table for you. You need to migrate using `south`.